# Apply the same git command to all projects inside one folder

Tags: git, netbeans

I usually have like 5 or more git projects open inside Netbeans (they are also stored at the same folder). I want to be able to do a "git pull", and then "git checkout master", and sometimes "git push" for all of them at once. Without having to click on each one of them.

It can be command line based or Netbeans plugin... anything!

Comment: Can you just write a script/whatever in your shell that loops over all the directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a bash script to do this, I did something similar a while back using below script

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOSITORIES=`pwd`

IFS=$'\n'

for REPO in `ls "$REPOSITORIES/"`
do
  if [ -d "$REPOSITORIES/$REPO" ]
  then
    echo "Updating $REPOSITORIES/$REPO at `date`"
    if [ -d "$REPOSITORIES/$REPO/.git" ]
    then
      cd "$REPOSITORIES/$REPO"
      echo "Pulling"
      git pull
    else
      echo "Skipping because it doesn't look like it has a .git folder."
    fi
    echo "Done at `date`"
    echo
  fi
done
```